# Share Object data between two scenes, but no materials

Tags: modeling, materials, linked-data, scene

My scene is planned for a realtime application.

I want to setup my lighting and materials on cycles, then bake some elements to lowpoly objects. Here an example scene : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42859

I bake *Selected to Active* (*HP_Cube* to *LP_Plane*) to the texture *LP_PLane*.

All i want in my 3d engine is *LP_Plane* with his texture applied to a standard material.

Problem : cycles material are not compatible and can't be exported to the engine.

So i want a new scene where i could keep the *LP_Plane* object, but switch to blender internal and assign a new standard material to my object.
Here i have made a new scene set to *full copy* http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42861 but of course if i modify *LP_Plane* in the first scene the mesh data is not echoed to *LP_Plane.001*

Is their a way to have duplicate linked objects between two scenes, each object having the same name but one with cycles material, the other with standard ?

*(and sorry if my english is shitty)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done. First, you need to create the two scenes where the Object Data is linked, but the objects are not. After that, you can setup the materials in a way so they are different in both scenes.

Start off by creating the second scene using 'Link Object data'. This will copy the object, but link the mesh data. That means, when you edit a mesh in one scene, its shape updates in the other as well.

[image: link scene]

Blender allows you to choose if the materials are linked to your Object or the Object Data. By default it links to Data, that means that somewhere in the datablock where the mesh is stored, the information which face receives which material is stored as well. Since both scenes share the same mesh data, the materials would always be the same in both of them.

[image: link to data]

In your case, you will need to set the Link to Object instead, like in the screenshot here:

[image: Link to Object]

Now the information which face has which material is stored in the Object. Again, for the two scenes, the objects are different, only the data is shared.

Note that when you switch your material link from Data to Object, the material slot will be emptied. Click on this Icon to browse through a list of materials to link it back:

[image: link to object]

In your 'Blender Render' scene you can now assign completely different materials to the same mesh. However, keep in mind that if you delete a material slot, it will disappear in both scenes!

Comment: Great thank you ! On top of that it's not a complex workflow :)

Comment: I make a test scene with a few explanations if some people want to play with this workflow : https://www.nothing-is-3d.com/dl/cycles_for_baking_BI_for_export.7z

Comment: glad it helped!